# How to calculate times in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table that has a column named time. How to calculate times in that column using SQL. Times are in HH:MM:SS format.

```
 time
04:00:00
00:25:38
04:32:58
01:12:23
00:00:00
```

So the total time is  10:10:59. So how do i get this answer using SQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time calculations with MySQL TIMEDIFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735628/time-calculations-with-mysql-timediff)

Comment: @clinomaniac I don't think so. I need to calculate seconds also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a39a09/4):

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `time` ) ) )
FROM `times`
```

Comment: Thank you soo much! This perfectly solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `TIME_TO_SEC` to convert your value into seconds, `SUM` the seconds up, and then use `SEC_TO_TIME` to get back into the time form

```
SELECT sec_to_time( sum( time_to_sec( `time` ) ) ) AS total_time  
FROM my_table
```

Comment: In MySQL, double quotes are treated as literal. You should either omit the quotes (Assuming your column name doesn't interfere with MySQL's reserved word list), or use `\``s.